# Android Crypto API list of intalled providers and transformations?

Tags: java, android, cryptography, version, provider

Is there a list of matching version of Android and installed providers of crypto algorithms?
AES,AES/CBC/PKCS7Padding,AES/EBC/PKCS7Padding etc

I want to use only those algorithms which will work on 100% of devices.

> Creates a new Cipher for the specified transformation. The installed
>        * providers are searched in order for an implementation of the specified
>        * transformation. The first found provider providing the transformation is
>        * used to create the cipher. If no provider is found an exception is
>        * thrown.

Comment: Why? Don't you just need one of them?

Comment: At the moment I need to know about support on devices the following algorithms:
"AES-256","AES/CBC/PKCS7Padding-256"

But for the future I would like to understand regarding the availability of other HASH functions, etc.